# htaccess - redirect to new domain while removing subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect to a new domain and remove the word "forum" from a URL. Like this:

`http://example.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=2525`

to

`http://example.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=2525`

There are a bunch of different strings that can come after "forum."

Here's what I have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org/forum/ [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

It redirects to the new domain but won't get rid of "forum." I've tried a bunch of different permutations. Nothing quite gets it.

Answer (score 2):

I found my own answer.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forum/(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps someone.